# Adding items on a table row after a click in React

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I'm creating a form that displays its input on a table, and every time I click on submit, the 1st row is added and the second is added too but not on the table. I'm not sure what's the issue.I'm thinking it could be because of how I manipulated the arrays that store the states? if not, what could be?

Here is my code:

```js
function Text(props) {
  var style = {
    paddingTop: 5,
    margin: 5
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={style}> {props.label} </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={props.name}
        style={style}
        value={props.labelInputText}
        onChange={props.changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
function TableFormList(props) {
  
  return(
    <table>
    <tr>
   {props.headers.map((item,index) => <th key={index}>{item}</th>)}
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
          {props.formElements.map((item,index) => <td key={index}>{item}</td> )}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    )
    }
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      items: []
    };
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.AddElementsOnSubmit = this.AddElementsOnSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  changeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  AddElementsOnSubmit() {
    var firstName = this.state.firstName;
    var lastName = this.state.lastName;

    var elements = this.state.items.slice();
    elements.push(firstName, lastName);
    this.setState({ items: elements, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  }

  render() {
    var style = {
      padding: 5,
      margin: 5
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Text
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          labelInputText={this.state.firstName}
          changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        />

        <Text
          label="Last Name"
          name="lastName"
          labelInputText={this.state.lastName}
          changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        />

   <input
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          style={style}
          onClick={() => this.AddElementsOnSubmit()}
        />
     
        <div>
          <TableFormList
            headers={["First Name", "Last Name"]}
            formElements={this.state.items}
          />
          

        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You should maybe put your map on the `<tr>` element instead of the `<td>`, that way for every item in your array, it creates a new row instead of just creating new cells.

Comment: I've tried it before and It doesn't work. It creates a <tr> for each state. The only solution that seemed to partially work was to replace var elements=this.state.items.slice() with var elements=[], but then everytime I hit submit, the new array erases the previous one.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're trying to accomplish then. Don't you want new rows created for every first and last name combination?

Comment: Yes, and that's been accomplished but what I'm having problems with is the display of the rows, for the first solution, the rows aren't displayed as they should (one row in each line), as for the second, only the new row is displayed (erases and replace the previous row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run map function for each table row, not table data. Also push person object to items array.

```
  elements.push({fName: firstName, lName: lastName});
```

```js
function Text(props) {
  var style = {
    paddingTop: 5,
    margin: 5
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={style}> {props.label} </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name={props.name}
        style={style}
        value={props.labelInputText}
        onChange={props.changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
function TableFormList(props) {
  
  return(
    <table>
    <tr>
   {props.headers.map((item,index) => <th key={index}>{item}</th>)}
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    
     {props.formElements.map((item,index) => <tr key={index}><td>{item.fName}</td><td>{item.lName}</td></tr> )}
    </tbody>
</table>
    )
    }
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      items: []
    };
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.AddElementsOnSubmit = this.AddElementsOnSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  changeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  AddElementsOnSubmit() {
    var firstName = this.state.firstName;
    var lastName = this.state.lastName;

    var elements = this.state.items.slice();
    elements.push({fName: firstName, lName: lastName});
    this.setState({ items: elements, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
  }

  render() {
    var style = {
      padding: 5,
      margin: 5
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Text
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          labelInputText={this.state.firstName}
          changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        />

        <Text
          label="Last Name"
          name="lastName"
          labelInputText={this.state.lastName}
          changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        />

   <input
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          style={style}
          onClick={() => this.AddElementsOnSubmit()}
        />
     
        <div>
          <TableFormList
            headers={["First Name", "Last Name"]}
            formElements={this.state.items}
          />
          

        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```